# iMac restarted 4 times in 24 hours because of a problem

Tags: kernel

I have a 2017 iMac, 27", with a Fusion HD and it has restarted 4 times over the past 24 hours.

I saved the last report.

Can anyone discern even a hint as to what is causing it looking at this report?

```
panic(cpu 0 caller 0xffffff800584aa3a): Kernel trap at 0xffffff7f86e03e7c, type 14=page fault, registers:
CR0: 0x000000008001003b, CR2: 0x0000000000000000, CR3: 0x0000000008734000, CR4: 0x00000000003626e0
RAX: 0x00000000152d0000, RBX: 0x0000000000000001, RCX: 0xffffff80060a5920, RDX: 0x0000000000000000
RSP: 0xffffff913a32be10, RBP: 0xffffff913a32be30, RSI: 0x00000000152d1561, RDI: 0x0000000000000000
R8:  0x00000000141e0009, R9:  0xffffff80060a3520, R10: 0x0000000000000500, R11: 0xffffff80188d7000
R12: 0x0000000000000000, R13: 0xffffff801db8d1d0, R14: 0xffffff8037d32780, R15: 0xffffff7f86e21290
RFL: 0x0000000000010202, RIP: 0xffffff7f86e03e7c, CS:  0x0000000000000008, SS:  0x0000000000000000
Fault CR2: 0x0000000000000000, Error code: 0x0000000000000000, Fault CPU: 0x0, PL: 0, VF: 1

Backtrace (CPU 0), Frame : Return Address
0xffffff913a32b870 : 0xffffff800571f5cd 
0xffffff913a32b8c0 : 0xffffff8005858b05 
0xffffff913a32b900 : 0xffffff800584a68e 
0xffffff913a32b950 : 0xffffff80056c5a40 
0xffffff913a32b970 : 0xffffff800571ec97 
0xffffff913a32ba70 : 0xffffff800571f087 
0xffffff913a32bac0 : 0xffffff8005ec27cc 
0xffffff913a32bb30 : 0xffffff800584aa3a 
0xffffff913a32bcb0 : 0xffffff800584a738 
0xffffff913a32bd00 : 0xffffff80056c5a40 
0xffffff913a32bd20 : 0xffffff7f86e03e7c 
0xffffff913a32be30 : 0xffffff8005e148a4 
0xffffff913a32bea0 : 0xffffff8005e146aa 
0xffffff913a32bec0 : 0xffffff8005761565 
0xffffff913a32bf40 : 0xffffff8005761091 
0xffffff913a32bfa0 : 0xffffff80056c513e 
      Kernel Extensions in backtrace:
         com.apple.iokit.IOUSBMassStorageDriver(157.121.1)[F60C120E-3A73-3BA9-BA89-705178C4EA68]@0xffffff7f86dff000->0xffffff7f86e32fff
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily(2.9)[BE052F4D-9B80-3FCD-B36D-BACB7DEE0DF2]@0xffffff7f86301000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOUSBHostFamily(1.2)[23C6290C-B42C-3885-B77D-09995CE04183]@0xffffff7f8637b000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOStorageFamily(2.1)[E13E9C61-F1F5-3A81-B1EF-65669C3CBDBF]@0xffffff7f86065000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIArchitectureModelFamily(422.120.3)[74ED4535-074E-31EB-A746-D057DA813124]@0xffffff7f865c1000

BSD process name corresponding to current thread: kernel_task

Mac OS version:
19F101

Kernel version:
Darwin Kernel Version 19.5.0: Tue May 26 20:41:44 PDT 2020; root:xnu-6153.121.2~2/RELEASE_X86_64
Kernel UUID: 54F1A78D-6F41-32BD-BFED-4381F9F6E2EF
Kernel slide:     0x0000000005400000
Kernel text base: 0xffffff8005600000
__HIB  text base: 0xffffff8005500000
System model name: iMac17,1 (Mac-DB15BD556843C820)
System shutdown begun: NO
Panic diags file available: YES (0x0)

System uptime in nanoseconds: 11890031126240
last loaded kext at 5813269124650: >!AXsanScheme    3 (addr 0xffffff7f88c62000, size 32768)
last unloaded kext at 777456303603: >!A!ILpssGspi   3.0.60 (addr 0xffffff7f871e2000, size 45056)
loaded kexts:
com.shinywhitebox.iShowU-Audio-Capture  1.0.5
|SCSITaskUserClient 422.120.3
>!ATopCaseHIDEventDriver    3430.1
@fileutil   20.036.15
>!AUpstreamUserClient   3.6.8
@kext.AMDFramebuffer    3.0.9
@kext.AMDRadeonX4000    3.0.9
@kext.AMDRadeonServiceManager   3.0.9
>AudioAUUC  1.70
>!AGraphicsDevicePolicy 5.2.4
@AGDCPluginDisplayMetrics   5.2.4
@filesystems.autofs 3.0
>!AHV   1
|IOUserEthernet 1.0.1
|IO!BSerialManager  7.0.5f6
>AGPM   111.4.4
>!APlatformEnabler  2.7.0d0
>X86PlatformShim    1.0.0
>pmtelemetry    1
>!AMikeyHIDDriver   131
@Dont_Steal_Mac_OS_X    7.0.0
>!A!ISKLGraphics    14.0.6
>!AHDA  283.15
>!AMikeyDriver  283.15
>!AThunderboltIP    3.1.4
|Broadcom!B20703USBTransport    7.0.5f6
|!ABCM5701Ethernet  10.3.5
>!A!IPCHPMC 2.0.1
>!ASMCLMU   212
>AirPort.BrcmNIC    1400.1.1
>eficheck   1
>!A!ISlowAdaptiveClocking   4.0.0
@kext.AMD7000!C 3.0.9
>!AMCCSControl  1.14
>!A!ISKLGraphicsFramebuffer 14.0.6
>!AVirtIO   1.0
@filesystems.hfs.kext   522.100.5
@!AFSCompression.!AFSCompressionTypeDataless    1.0.0d1
@BootCache  40
@!AFSCompression.!AFSCompressionTypeZlib    1.0.0
>!ASDXC 1.7.7
@filesystems.apfs   1412.120.2
@private.KextAudit  1.0
>!AAHCIPort 341.0.2
>!ARTC  2.0
>!AACPIButtons  6.1
>!AHPET 1.8
>!ASMBIOS   2.1
>!AACPIEC   6.1
>!AAPIC 1.7
$!AImage4   1
@nke.applicationfirewall    303
$TMSafetyNet    8
@!ASystemPolicy 2.0.0
|EndpointSecurity   1
>!AXsanScheme   3
>!UAudio    323.1
>usb.cdc    5.0.0
>!AMultitouchDriver 3440.1
>!AInputDeviceSupport   3440.8
>!AHS!BDriver   3430.1
>IO!BHIDDriver  7.0.5f6
@kext.AMDRadeonX4030HWLibs  1.0
@kext.AMDRadeonX4000HWServices  3.0.9
>!AGraphicsControl  5.2.4
@kext.triggers  1.0
|IOAVB!F    850.1
>!ASSE  1.0
@plugin.IOgPTPPlugin    840.3
>DspFuncLib 283.15
@kext.OSvKernDSPLib 529
@!AGPUWrangler  5.2.4
|IONDRVSupport  576.1
|Broadcom!BHost!CUSBTransport   7.0.5f6
|IO!BHost!CUSBTransport 7.0.5f6
|IO!BHost!CTransport    7.0.5f6
|IO!B!F 7.0.5f6
|IO!BPacketLogger   7.0.5f6
>!AHIDKeyboard  209
>!AHDA!C    283.15
|IOHDA!F    283.15
|IOEthernetAVB!C    1.1.0
>!ASMBusPCI 1.0.14d1
|IO80211!F  1200.12.2b1
>mDNSOffloadUserClient  1.0.1b8
>corecapture    1.0.4
|IOSkywalk!F    1
>X86PlatformPlugin  1.0.0
>IOPlatformPlugin!F 6.0.0d8
|IOSlowAdaptiveClocking!F   1.0.0
>!AThunderboltEDMSink   4.2.3
@kext.AMDSupport    3.0.9
>!ASMBus!C  1.0.18d1
@!AGraphicsDeviceControl    5.2.4
|IOAccelerator!F2   438.5.4
|IOGraphics!F   576.1
>usb.!UHub  1.2
>usb.networking 5.0.0
>usb.!UHostCompositeDevice  1.2
|IOAudio!F  300.2
@vecLib.kext    1.2.0
|IOSerial!F 11
|IOSurface  269.11
@filesystems.hfs.encodings.kext 1
>!AThunderboltDPOutAdapter  6.2.6
>!AThunderboltDPInAdapter   6.2.6
>!AThunderboltDPAdapter!F   6.2.6
>!AThunderboltPCIDownAdapter    2.5.4
>!AThunderboltNHI   5.8.6
|IOThunderbolt!F    7.6.1
|IONVMe!F   2.1.0
|IOAHCIBlock!S  316.100.5
|IOUSB!F    900.4.2
|IOAHCI!F   290.0.1
>usb.!UXHCIPCI  1.2
>usb.!UXHCI 1.2
>!AEFINVRAM 2.1
>!AEFIRuntime   2.1
|IOSMBus!F  1.1
|IOHID!F    2.0.0
$quarantine 4
$sandbox    300.0
@kext.!AMatch   1.0.0d1
>DiskImages 493.0.0
>!AFDEKeyStore  28.30
>!AEffaceable!S 1.0
>!AKeyStore 2
>!UTDM  489.120.1
|IOSCSIBlockCommandsDevice  422.120.3
>!ACredentialManager    1.0
>KernelRelayHost    1
>!ASEPManager   1.0.1
>IOSlaveProcessor   1
|IOTimeSync!F   840.3
|IONetworking!F 3.4
|IOUSBMass!SDriver  157.121.1
|IOSCSIArchitectureModel!F  422.120.3
|IO!S!F 2.1
|IOUSBHost!F    1.2
>!UHostMergeProperties  1.2
>usb.!UCommon   1.0
>!ABusPower!C   1.0
|CoreAnalytics!F    1
>!AMobileFileIntegrity  1.0.5
@kext.CoreTrust 1
|IOReport!F 47
>!AACPIPlatform 6.1
>!ASMC  3.1.9
>watchdog   1
|IOPCI!F    2.9
|IOACPI!F   1.4
@kec.pthread    1
@kec.Libm   1
@kec.corecrypto 1.0
```

Comment: It could be memory.  I would start with Apple Diagnostics.  Boot while holding the `D` key and see what results you get

Answer (score 1):

I found this same suggestion elsewhere along with the advice that it might be associated with a USB-connected device.

I disconnected my Anker powered USB hub from my iMac.  I had a Sabrent external HDD enclosure plugged into the Anker and it is now plugged directly into the iMac.

I have had odd things happen with the Anker USB hub in the past and was a bit surprised because Anker is not your usual cheap Chinese crap - they get consistently good reviews on multiple Mac sites.

It's been two days now and no more kernel panics; I am just about 99% sure this is going to do it.

BTW, is it "D" or Option + D to get Apple Diagnostics?

Comment: That’s surprising for Anker - it may be a manufacturing defect or a defective IC. Hold D for diagnostic mode